# Laravel Joins with same table again and again

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

This is the current code of my joins.

```
$vehicleTransferNotifications=DB::table('vehicle_transfer_notifications')
                                        ->join('vehicle_requests', 'vehicle_transfer_notifications.request_id', '=', 'vehicle_requests.id')
                                        // ->join('users', 'vehicle_requests.users_id', '=', 'users.id')
                                        // ->join('companies', 'users.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                                        // ->join('companies', 'vehicle_transfer_notifications.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                                        ->join('vehicles', 'vehicle_requests.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
                                        ->join('companies', 'vehicles.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                                        ->join('vehicle_types', 'vehicles.vehicle_type_id', '=', 'vehicle_types.id')
                                        ->join('vehicle_make', 'vehicles.make_id', '=', 'vehicle_make.id')
                                        ->select('vehicle_transfer_notifications.*','vehicle_transfer_notifications.id as notification_id','vehicle_transfer_notifications.seen as is_seen','vehicle_requests.*','vehicles.reg_no','vehicle_types.type','vehicle_make.name','companies.name as company_name')
                                        ->where('vehicle_transfer_notifications.company_id','=',auth()->user()->company_id)
                                        ->get();
```

Now I want add something like I have comment in my code.How I add to this join query? Because I have already join my query with companies table so how can I join again with the companies table and get something like `companies.name` again in the select query?

Comment: You can join with the same table again if you provide an alias for that table. For example join('companies AS c1', 'users.company_id', '=', 'c1.id') and use c1.name in select to get the company name. Is there any reason you are not using Eloquent and relationships?

Comment: @AhmedShefeer no special reason. I felt like this is easy for me.I'm not that much aware of eloquent relationships. Is this wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach, in fact your code will be more db efficient since it gets all the results in one db query. Using relationships makes it easier to write code and the queries will be cleaner and more "readable", but to achieve the result above it would execute multiple queries on the db.

Answer (score 0):

You should give **alias** to `companies` table as per your requirement.
use that **alias** for fetch data instead of `companies`

```
$vehicleTransferNotifications=DB::table('vehicle_transfer_notifications')
                                        ->join('vehicle_requests', 'vehicle_transfer_notifications.request_id', '=', 'vehicle_requests.id')
                                        ->join('vehicles', 'vehicle_requests.vehicle_id', '=', 'vehicles.id')
                                        ->join('companies as company_one', 'users.company_id', '=', 'company_one.id')
                                        ->join('companies as company_two', 'vehicle_transfer_notifications.company_id', '=', 'company_two.id')
                                        ->join('companies as company_three', 'vehicles.company_id', '=', 'company_three.id')
                                        ->join('vehicle_types', 'vehicles.vehicle_type_id', '=', 'vehicle_types.id')
                                        ->join('vehicle_make', 'vehicles.make_id', '=', 'vehicle_make.id')
                                        ->select('company_one.name as company_name_one', 'company_two.name as company_name_two', 'company_three.name as company_name_three', 'vehicle_transfer_notifications.*','vehicle_transfer_notifications.id as notification_id','vehicle_transfer_notifications.seen as is_seen','vehicle_requests.*','vehicles.reg_no','vehicle_types.type','vehicle_make.name')
                                        ->where('vehicle_transfer_notifications.company_id','=',auth()->user()->company_id)
                                        ->get();
```